# PHP - Correct way to define Site_Root and App_Root

Tags: php, path, constants, document-root

I have these 2 constants defined:

```
define( 'SITE_ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' );

define( 'APP_ROOT', str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/' );
```

My folder structure is like this:

```
Site_Root (exampledomain.com)
   - docs
   - tests
   - app
      - assets
      - libs
      - core
```

If I use something like :

```
$appassets = APP_ROOT.'assets/css/'.$filename.'.css';
```

it echos the path as:

```
http://exampledomain.com/var/www/app/assets/css/core.css
```

How can I get rid of this `var/www/` bit from the echoed path?

I want the value of 'SITE_ROOT' to be 'http://exampledomain.com/'

and the value of 'APP_ROOT' to be 'http://exampledomain.com/app/'

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
define( 'APP_ROOT', '/app/');
```

if you *really* need a constant for this